# Amd drivers for Ubuntu 18.10

Tags: drivers, graphics, amd-graphics

I been using Ubuntu 18.04 for months, Last night it was working fine but when logged back today it was showing me black screen. So i just installed new Ubuntu 18.10 and try to install AMD graphic driver and i can't find driver for Ubuntu 18.10 and now I'm struck with AMD Oland.

Card AMD Radeon HD 8570 OEM

```
lspci -vnn | grep VGA -A 12
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Oland [Radeon HD 8570 / R7 240/340 OEM] [1002:6611] (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Dell Oland [Radeon HD 8570 / R7 240/340 OEM] [1028:2121]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 34
    Memory at e0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    Memory at f7dc0000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256K]
    I/O ports at dc00 [size=256]
    Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: radeon
    Kernel modules: radeon, amdgpu

01:00.1 Audio device [0403]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Cape Verde/Pitcairn HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 7700/7800 Series] [1002:aab0]
    Subsystem: Dell Cape Verde/Pitcairn HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 7700/7800 Series] [1028:aab0]
```

Comment: There are no installable drivers for this GPU. It should work out of the box.

Comment: What you suggest, should i reinstall ubuntu 18.04 but now there is 18.04.2  and driver support i think is for 18.04.1

Comment: You don't need any driver on either release.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with AMD Oland, it is the Linux driver of your motherboard. Another option would be to get the graphic card Oibaf PPA, but it won’t do miracles and you get 2-3 patches every day (MESA 19.1).  Your choice!

We do have similar results (AMD Raven) for the given command line with Mesa 19.1 PPA.

https://launchpad.net/~oibaf/+archive/ubuntu/graphics-drivers

```
glxinfo | grep "OpenGL version"
OpenGL version string: 4.5 (Compatibility Profile) Mesa 19.1.0-devel (git-f84f833 2019-02-19 bionic-oibaf-ppa)
```